# EF Making Links but still getting errors

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm evolving here and making progress it appears. Last week I'd posted a question and gotten some responses that made although they didn't give me an answer did make me question some of the things that I had tried and made me go back to rework some configurations of my database tables a bit to see if that would prove to be more conducive to the EF approach which as I've mentioned is entirely new to me coming back to web development after being way for many years.

I tried several different things including some foreign key options but because I'm dealing with larger 1 to many relationships that was going to be problematic as well. As it ended up it flat out wasn't working. My last attempt was this morning when I restructured the tables to include all fields that were included in my associations inside the primary keys of the four tables.

I then re-created the EF Data Model for the project and built associations for each of the tables linking ONLY the fields values that were valid for the link between each of the associations. This mean that in some cases as you'll see below some elements of a tables key were left without matches assigned to them. I wasn't sure if I could get away with this or not. But to my surprise I was successful in establishing an association between all of the tables as I had intended for the first time since starting this project. I'm attaching the model diagram here though I doubt it will be helpful for this discussion. [EF Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MKsm.jpg)

Now, I may be okay or I may still be in the weeds. I will et you experts tell me how I stand here. The result of this is that I've pulled up two new errors repeated twice. One set of errors for the association between GETT_Family_Group_List and GETT_Elements tables and the other is for the association between GETT_Elemenets and GETT_Documents tables.  Virtually the same issue so I'm only going to talk about the first one and not the second one, because, if and when we come up with a solution for the first that should apply to the second as well. here are the two errors that I'm getting for each of these:

> Error 111: Properties referred by the Principal Role
>   GETT_Family_Group_List must be exactly identical to the key of the
>   EntityType ARFSModel. GETT_Family_Group_List referred to by the
>   Principal Role in the relationship constraint for Relationship
>   ARFSModel.GETF_Family_GroupjistGErf_Elements. Make sure all the key
>   properties are specified in the Principal Role.
>
> Running transformation: Properties referred by the Principal Role
>   GETT_Family_Group_List must be exactly identical to the key of the
>   EntityType ARFSModel.GETT_Family_Group_List referred to by the
>   Principal Role in the relationship constraint for Relationship
>   ARFSModel.GETT_Family_Group_ListGETI_Elements. Make sure all the key
>   properties are specified in the Principal Role.

The tables layouts related to these two tables that are pulling these two errors as well as the Referential Constraint look like this:  [Tables and Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1cUM.jpg)

That's about it... I supplied you with about all I can think of. Let me know if you need more and I will try to provide it.
Thanks and regards,
Ken...

### EDITED:

```
Properties
 ARFSModel.GETT_Family_Group_ListGETT_Element Association
  - Constraints
     Referential Contraint      GETT_Family_Group_List -> GETT_Elements
  - General
     Association Set Name       Gett_Family_Group_ListGET_Elements
  - Documentation
     Long Description
     Summary
     End1 Multiplicity           1 (One of GET_Family_Group_List)
     End1 Navigation Property    GETT_Elements
     End1 OnDelete               None
     End1 RoleName               GETT_Family_Group_List
     End2 Multiplicity           * (collection of GETT_Elements)
     End2 Navigation Property)   GETT_Family_Group_List
     END2 OnDelete               None
     End2 Role Name              GETT_Elements
     Name                        GETT_Family_Group_ListGETT_Elements
```

Hopefully this is more readable!
Regards,
Ken...

Comment: And after all these words you don't show an essential part: the properties involved in the associations. That's where the shoe pinches.

Comment: Please edit your question. But I'm looking for which properties in the referee class refer to which properties in the referred class. One thing: you always have to refer to the *full key* of an entity.

Comment: Okay... not to confuse things but I deleted my two other comments here because they included the nearly unintelligible reference information and notes related to it and now have redone that in the edited question. Thanks for putting me on to that, I wasn't aware I could re-edit the question with additional comments and thereby use the format option there. MUCH more neat! Think that makes more sense.